# a href javascript link adds unwanted hash value in address bar

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a javascript link

```
<a href="javascript:hideSideBar();" style="color: #fcfcfc;" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Hide Comments" data-placement="right"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> </a>
```

that calls this function

```
function hideSideBar(ID) {
    var selector = ".sidebar";
    if (ID !== undefined) {
        selector = "#" + ID + selector;
    }
    $(selector).hide("slide",{ direction: "right" });
    $(".sidebar-btn").show("slide",{ direction: "right" });
}
```

that for some reason adds `'#javascript:hideSideBar();'` to the address bar.

this is the only place where it does that and I can't figure out why it does that or how to get rid of it?

Comment: Please add fiddle

Comment: Never use `href="javascript:..."` unless you are writing a bookmarklet. Either use a real link with a server side fallback and then event.preventDefault(); or use a button instead of a link.

Comment: Try providing a [mcve]. I suspect the problem is caused by some other JS on the page.

Comment: Quentin, I was able to use a button - thank you
I'm still not sure why this happens but the button has the correct behavior and doesn't foul up the addressbar

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve what I needed with this

```
<a href="javascript:hideSideBar();" class="btn btn-default" role="button"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> </a>
```